# Docker Docker0 bridge not getting new IP

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have updated my daemon.json to update the IP/Subnet so as it no longer conflicts with the corporate network, however the `docker0` bridge still has the old ip-range after restarting.

```
{
    "bip": "192.168.5.0/24",
    "default-gateway": "10.31.99.129",
    "dns": [
        "10.31.96.21"
    ]
}


root@8f61ab846912:/src# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
3: ip6tnl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1452 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
10: eth0@if11: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:12:00:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.18.0.3/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@8f61ab846912:/src#
```

Comment: Did you restart docker daemon?

Comment: Yup - as stated in Q